# Add specific column length padding to an already populated column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table column filled with values. The Column is set to Varchar(100). The problem I have is that I need to take whatever data is there and expand it out with "Padding" until each one is 100 characters.

All of this goes into a fixed width flat file.

Each entry in the column is between 20 and 30 characters right now. The padding I will be adding is "blank spaces"

My problem is that I am not sure how to write an update statement to handle updating the existing data. I have already fixed the future data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need to pad it?

Comment: @Xedni "...goes into a fixed width, flat file".

Comment: Got that, but what means is he using where the OP can't specify the file as being fixed width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with an `update`.  The simplest method, though, is probably to change the type to `char(100)`:

```
alter table t alter column col char(100);
```

`char()` pads values with spaces on the right.

Alternatively, you can just do:

```
update t
    set col = col + replicate(' ', 100);
```

I don't think SQL Server complains about the size difference.  If you are concerned about a potential error, you can do:

```
update t
    set col = col + replicate(' ', 100 - len(col));
```

Comment: ... or `LEFT(col + replicate(' ', 100), 100)`